# Why is this relation not transitive?

Tags: relations

Question: Let $A$ be $\{a,b,c\}$. Let the relation $R$ be $A \times A$ - $\{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b), (c,a)\}$ Which of the following statements about $R$ is true?
a. $R$ is reflexive, is symmetric, and is transitive.
b. $R$ is reflexive, is symmetric, and is not transitive.
c. $R$ is not reflexive, is not symmetric, and is not transitive.
d. $R$ is not reflexive, is symmetric, and is not transitive.
e. $R$ is reflexive, is not symmetric, and is transitive.
I understand why the relation is neither reflexive nor symmetric but as for whether it's not transitive I kind of understand why its not but cannot explain it.

For a relation to be transitive $(a R b) ∧ (b R z) → (a R z)$ but in the context of the question this becomes $(a R b) ∧ (b R b) → (a R b)$ however since I since I already used the ordered pair $(a R b)$ in the premise I understand I can't use it again so that being said how do I explain why it is not transitive?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the one you are discussing (note that the elements of $A\times A-\{(a,a),(a,b),(b,b),(c,a)\}$ are all the elements of $A\times A$ without those specified after the $"-"$, so you do not even have $(a,b)$ or $(b,b)$ in $\mathcal{R}$).

Rather note that you have $(c,b)$ and $(b,c)$ in $\mathcal{R}$ but not $(c,c)$.

Comment: In a similar question the relation is A x A - {(b,b),(c,b).} So how would I go explaining why this relation is transitive? I understand what you are showing I should have rephrased the question so it specifies just what I was showing.

Comment: In this case it is also not transitive: since in $A\times A-\{(b,b),(c,b)\}$ you have $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ but not $(c,b)$, the transitivity cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Note that $(c,b) \in R, (b,b)\in R $ and $(c, b) $ is also in R. Finished.

Comment: @baloown What do you mean the transitivity cannot be guaranteed?

Comment: I mean the relation is not transitive.

Comment: @Baloown Oh so would the explanation be more in the sense that you can never have two of the same ordered pairs in a relation and so transitivity can never be satisfied?

Comment: In my first comment there is an error, we should read "you have $(b,a)$ and $(a,b)$ but not $(b,b)$". No, relations are sets and in sets the repetition of elements doesn't count: $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$. Here the this relation is not transitive since you have $b\mathcal{R}a$ and $a\mathcal{R}b$, but no $b\mathcal{R}b$.

Answer (score 1):

$(c,a) \in R$, $(a.b) \in R$ but $(c,b)$ not in $R$